# Set value to radio button after click on button using angular model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a set of radio buttons that when I click them they show different content.

```
<div class="radio" ng-init="topRadios()">
 <input type="radio" ng-model="topTable" value="topCategory" ng-change="updateTotals('topCategory')">TY  30 Categories</label>
 <input type="radio" ng-model="topTable" value="topSupplier" ng-change="updateTotals('topSupplier')">TY Top 10 Suppliers</label>
 <input type="radio" ng-model="topTable" value="topBrand" ng-change="updateTotals('topBrand')">TY Top 10 Brands</label>

</div>
```

And I have a button to apply some filters to the information that is displayed depending o the radio button selection.

```
 <button class="goButton btn btn-xs" ng-class="css" ng-click="go()" ng-disabled="isClicked"> Apply </button>
```

When I click on the third button to see that info for example and then the Apply button with some filters the page refresh and what I want is that when the info and radio buttons displayed the first radio button is selected.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Need to explain the `page refresh` in more detail. Reload view or reload whole page?

Comment: need to store data in a service if you want that same data available when view changes

Comment: actually it's stored in a service, when I click the apply button returns differente data, but what I want is to reload the radio buttons and see the info of the first radio.

Comment: Need to see how service and controller work then

Answer (score 1):

sounds like what you want to do is set an initial value for your radio input's `ng-model` in your controller:

```
$scope.topTable = 'topCategory';
```

you probably also want to reset the input's value in your `go` function after you apply your filtering with that same code snippet.

Comment: Yes, that's wan I want, reset the input's value!

Comment: Actually the topRadio function is set to make topCategory the default value, when i load the view the category radio button is checked, the thing is when I move to any of the other two, and then change the filters and click on the apply button the view reloads and stay in the second or third radio depending on my selection and what I want is to go to the firs radio..